# Setting the type of a hard coded string in a column_property in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the following model using flask_sqlalchemy:

```
class Student(DB.Model):
    """A student."""

    id_: DB.Mapped[uuid.UUID] = DB.mapped_column(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4
    )
    first_name: DB.Mapped[str] = DB.mapped_column(StrippedString(16))
    last_name: DB.Mapped[str] = DB.mapped_column(StrippedString(32))
    full_name: DB.Mapped[str] = DB.column_property(
        first_name + " " + last_name,
    )
```

Whenever printing out `full_name`, the space in between is not there. I figured that this is because `first_name` is of type `StrippedString`:

```
class StrippedString(TypeDecorator):
    """An augmented string type.

    It strips whitespace upon the binding of the value as a parameter to a
    query.
    """

    impl = DB.String
    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        """Strip the value (if it exists) from leading and trailing whitespace."""
        return value.strip() if value else None
```

The `process_bind_param` function above is applied to the `" "` as well, resulting in no space between `first_name` and `last_name`.

If I change the column type of `first_name` to `DB.String(16)`, all is well. Except, of course, I wait to retain the `StrippedString` type for `first_name`.

So, now is my question: how can I set (or influence) the type of the plain string `" "`? Basically, I want the hard coded `" "` to be left alone, and not seen as another `StrippedString`.

Comment: Is there a concatenation operation similar to `" ".join([first_name, last_name])`? I think the issue is that `first_name + " "` is evalutated first, and the resulting string has trailing whitespace that needs to be stripped; *that* string is then "added" to `last_name`. You probably need an operation that builds the final result directly, so there is never a temporary string with trailing or leading space.

Comment: try casting one of them to a string `column_property(cast(first_name, String(16)) + " " + last_name)`, `cast` is `from sqlalchemy import cast`

Comment: Wonderful! @python_user got me out of the conundrum: casting is indeed a solution.

Thank you @chepner for your contribution. However, `pudb` taught me that somewhere a `" ".strip()"` is being evaluated, so it's the entire hardcoded string which is seen as the same type as the first, variable string, I believe. Which also explains @python_user's solution.

Comment: glad to have helped, feel free to self answer as you see fit @BartVanLoon

Comment: did just that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per @python_user's comment to the question, the solution is rather straightforward:

```
full_name: DB.Mapped[str] = DB.column_property(cast(first_name, DB.String) + " " + last_name)
```

does the trick.

What I believe is going on is that SQLAlchemy is trying to be smart about the type of the concatenated elements. The first one being a `StrippedString` in my original question, it applies the same type to the second one (the literal `" "`), which - of course - results in an empty string.

In this new scenario, the first type is `String`, so this is applied to the second one, maintaining the hard coded space between first and last name.

Problem solved!